# Pulling currency values from other websites

Tags: php, currency

I would like to pull values of specific currencies from websites which update them regularly. Because I need to convert only euro to few foreign currencies. Is that possible or should I create my own database and update it?

Answer (score 2):

by calling this xml 
http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/EUR/rss.xml

```
$url = "http://themoneyconverter.com/rss-feed/EUR/rss.xml";
            $cont = file_get_contents($url);
             $xml = new SimpleXMLElement($cont);
$feeds = "AED/EUR"; //// currency rate for United Arab Emirates Dirham
                   ///// You can use it as session
        foreach ($xml->channel->item as $xml2){
            if ($xml2->title==$feeds){
            $xml2->description."<br>";
            preg_match('/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/', $xml2->description, $matches);
            $rate = $matches[0];
      }    
  }
```

I hope this will help you :)